# Facebook graph api search events by place id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I know you can get events by place id by getting /place_id/events
but that only returns events created by the Facebook page of the place.
There are public events created by other pages/users with that place id that are not returned by the query. How could i get all the events with that place id, including those not created by the place's Facebook page?

For instance, if you get this event: 864962223628776
the place id returned is 304911119548447

But if you get /304911119548447/events the query is not returning the event 864962223628776 because it is created by another user/page.